# How to scroll a child component to parent component top in React using scrollIntoView

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

onClick  of Panel1, Panel2, or Panel3 I would like to scroll clicked Panel to the very top of the parent container so the Panel will always be aligned to the top of the parent container (panelN is an accordion which opens up, and I'd like to present the accordion data at the top of my parent container).

I'm using React.

Can't get it to work, do I assign another useRef to the parent container? then scroll refPanel1 to parentContaierRef?

If so, what is the notation?

Thanks in advance.